# How to toggle breakpoints on jsonc files in VSCode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm developing debug adapter that needs to toggle breakpoints on jsonc file. I could open .json files and set breakpoints there but not to .jsonc files.

i tried to set `"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true` to true but did not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: fyi: I can reproduce this on VS Code 1.85.2. not sure why one would want to do this, but I think it's still a valid, clear question.